# How to download a file into a directory using curl or wget?

Tags: linux, macos, curl, wget

I know I can use the following 2 commands to download a file:

```
curl -O example.com/file.zip
wget example.com/file.zip
```

But I want them to go into a specific directory. So I can do the following:

```
curl -o mydir/file.zip example.com/file.zip
wget -O mydir/file.zip example.com/file.zip
```

Is there a way to not have to specify the filename? Something like this:

```
curl -dir mydir example.com/file.zip
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The following line will download all the files to a directory mentioned by you.

```
wget -P /home/test www.xyz.com
```

Here the files will be downloaded to `/home/test` directory

Comment: Worked for me too! I also needed the options ;  --user user --password pass .

Comment: If you are currently in a dir, say the Documents dir. With path Documents/home/test, the hyphen before "home" must be removed for wget to function.

Comment: How can I do the same behavior with `curl`?

Comment: @VictorBocharsky One might think that this would be `curl --output-dir /some/directory -O https://some.domain.org/download/link`, but it only works for real links without redirects (or whatever that is called). E.g. `curl --output-dir /tmp -O "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=en-US"`  does **not** work, whereas `curl --output-dir /tmp -O "$(curl -L --head -w '%{url_effective}' "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=en-US" 2>/dev/null | tail -n1)"` will.

Answer (score 20):

I know this is an old question but it is possible to do what you ask with curl

```
rm directory/somefile.zip
rmdir directory
mkdir directory
curl --http1.1 http://example.com/somefile.zip --output directory/somefile.zip
```

first off if this was scripted you would need to make sure the file if it already exist is deleted then delete the directory then curl the download otherwise curl will fail with a file and directory already exist error.

Comment: This is exactly what was aleeady in the question. The question was for selecting a directoriy but keeping the file name.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is to `cd` inside a subshell

```
  (cd somedir; wget example.com/file.zip)
```

and you could make that a shell function (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc`)

```
  wgetinside() {
    ( cd $1 ; shift; wget $* )
  }
```

then type `wgetinside somedir http://example.com/file.zip`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no as curl and wget automatically writes to STDOUT. It does not have an option built into to place the download file into a directory.

```
-o/--output <file> Write output to <file> instead of stdout (Curl)

-O,  --output-document=FILE    write documents to FILE. (WGet)
```

But as it outputs to STDOUT natively it does give you programatic solutions such as the following:

```
 i="YOURURL"; f=$(awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' <<< $i);curl $i > ~/$f
```

The first i will define your url (example.com/file.zip) as a variable. The f= part removed the URL and leaves /file.zip and then you curl that file ($i) to the directory (~) as the file name.

Comment: You could use `basename` instead of your `awk` trick. `basename` is working on URLs (because it uses the last `/`)

Comment: Documentation for -o says: >> The file will be saved in the current working directory. If you want the file saved in a different directory, make sure you change the current working directory before invoking curl with this option.